# Objective-C passing NSError pointer to NSFileManager within custom method

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsfilemanager, nserror

I have a method that uses ARC and takes an NSError pointer and I pass that into the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` like so:

```
+ (NSArray *) getContentsOfCurrentDirectoryWithError: (NSError **)error
{
    // code here

    _contentsOfCurrentDirectory = [_fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: _documentDirectory error: error];

    // more code here
}
```

I'm not sure if this code is correct, because I'm not very used to pointers due to being spoiled by managed languages.  However, my initial reaction was to do this:

```
_contentsOfCurrentDirectory = [_fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: _documentDirectory error: &error];
```

Xcode yelled at me for trying it like that, though.  My assumption as to how this might work is that the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method is asking for a pointer and, since I was asking for a pointer in my `getContentsOfCurrentDirectoryWithError:error:` method, I can just pass `error` without using the dereference operator.

I just want to make sure I'm doing this right to avoid hassle later, so is there a problem with what I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method can be like this **NSError **errorMessage** in .h file:

```
+ (NSArray *) getContentsOfCurrentDirectory
{ 
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *_documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
  NSArray *_contentsOfCurrentDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManger]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: _documentDirectory error: errorMessage]; 
  return contentsOfCurrentDirectory ;
}
```

Whenever error occurs **errorMessage** reference will have error message [error description]

Comment: Well, I had intended for my custom method to be able to expose any errors that may have been encountered by the inner method.